# A system-wide way to set or get $JAVA_HOME in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, path, java

I wonder whether Ubuntu itself provides a system-wide way to find the current `JAVA_HOME` or whether there is right place for setting `JAVA_HOME`.

Mac OS X does well in this, for `/usr/libexec/java_home` command returns the current `JAVA_HOME`. But to Ubuntu, the materials I found always told me to set the `$JAVA_PATH` pointing to a static path, which is stored in `~/.bash_profile`.

I think, however, this approach has several drawbacks:

1. Once Java updates, the mini version number will change, which makes the static path no longer available.
2. After changing the JRE used in my system with `update-alternatives`, I have to modify `$JAVA_HOME` in `.bash_profile`. That extra work is annoying.
3. Some `$JAVA_HOME`-required programs, is not aware of `.bash_profile` at all. I have to set `$JAVA_HOME` in their start-up script, therefore a standard-and-easy way to get `$JAVA_HOME` seems critical to me.

Well, any advice is welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A little hacky, but put this line in your `/etc/profile` for setting it system-wide:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -e /usr/bin/javac)))
```

Comment: Some sysadmins like to fiddle with the PATH so the /usr/bin isn't necessarily the first place looked. To be sure you are picking up the path of the version you will actually run, a better re-hack may be:  

    `export JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -e $(which javac))))`

Comment: this works if the path exists. Is there any way to make it silent on systems that don't have java?

Comment: how to do this in Mac? "readlink -e" doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can set environment variables in `/etc/environment`, which gets setup by PAM. There should also be symlinks in `/usr/lib/jvm` which don't change with minor releases.

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution byuser13742 assumes that the server definitely has Java installed. In case you're adding this to a centralized script for many servers it will give some errors like:

```
dirname: missing operand
Try 'dirname --help' for more information.
```

To avoid that and only set JAVA_HOME if the server has a Java environment, a slight enhancement is:

```
if [ -f "$(which javac)" ]; then
    export JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -e $(which javac))))
fi
```

I also incorporated the change from SimonB to use `which` to find where the installation is.

Comment: Can I put this into `/etc/environment`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure the 'java' command can be called, wouldn't this work for you?

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $(java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 | grep 'java\.home' | awk '{ print $3 }'))
```

Comment: The OP is looking for a way to set `$JAVA_HOME` system-wide, not just in the current shell.

Answer (score -1):

Set path system profile

Edit the system Path file /etc/profile

```
sudo gedit /etc/profile
```

Add following lines in end

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

For http://javaandme.com/ for full installation guide.